# What is the "200" in this shell redirection command? File descriptor?

Tags: shell, file, redirect, descriptor

What is the "200" in this command? I assume it's a file descriptor but why 200? Is that a safe choice in all cases?

```
(
flock -s 200

# ... commands executed under lock ...

) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

I copied this from the [flock man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).

Here's how I would have coded it. Here I'm only locking access to one command, `sleep 1`. I like the above version because it supports locking a batch of commands. But I want to understand it before I use it.

```
flock -x /var/lock/mylockfile sleep 1
```

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy . I removed the redundant touch command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `200` is a file descriptor in the above syntax. When the user picks a FD to redirect, the shell "routes around" that choice: If 200 were *previously* put to shell-internal use, the shell then copies it to a different number and respects the user's choice. Thus, the only conflicts you need to worry about are those with other user-provided code and tools (and of course standard FDs -- 0/1/2).

It's not guaranteed by the POSIX spec that `200` will be a legal number -- the mandated number of addressable FDs in POSIX-y shells is much, *much* lower -- but on a modern system it won't be a problem.

With bash 4.1 and later, you can have the shell itself pick an available FD.

```
(
   exec {lock_fd}>/var/lock/mylockfile
   flock -x "$lock_fd"
   # commands to do with the lock held
)
```